# Proper way to pass %like% param with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the query below,

```
public function getSearchResult($searchString){
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM company t WHERE t.company_name like ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", "%".$searchString."%");
        $stmt->execute();
        $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $tasks;
    }
```

Error I am getting is

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in

I guess I am doing the like param incorrectly (as it works for where = condition). I am pretty new to slim, any help?

Comment: You can pass it in the execute as an array like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to form the string before you can use it in `bind_param()`

```
public function getSearchResult($searchString){
   $search = '%'. $searchString . '%';
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM company t WHERE t.company_name like ? ");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $search);
   $stmt->execute();
   $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
   $stmt->close();
   return $tasks;
}
```

In addition it *looks* like you're passing a string, not an integer, make sure you set the type to `"s"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set where your i variable goes.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM company t WHERE t.company_name LIKE :i ");
$stmt->bind_param(":i", "%$searchString%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

[Here is an example in php.net](http://php.net/manual/tr/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
public function getSearchResult($searchString){
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM company t WHERE t.company_name like ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", "%$searchString%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $tasks;
    }
```

Search string in where condition so it would be `s` and add `PDO::PARAM_STR`